# Why won't my Ubuntu 19.10 connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, live-usb

I am using Ubuntu on a USB. When I do ifconfig, it always says "no wireless extensions" for lo and the others don't exist. When I go to settings, the WiFi settings says that I need a WiFi adapter. So far I have done the the things in the other duplicate questions, and none worked. The computer I am using is [https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-130S-11IGM-Laptop-Celeron-Windows/dp/B07RHMBGCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RHMBGCF). If there is any more information that you need to know, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This was the common issue in some type of laptops like hp.
Below Tutorial was helped me to detect my wireless adapter. Please watch this 
 [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbrYpqHadVQ) to recognise your wireless adapter. 
Follow these steps

````
 1. Please install make command
 2. ```sudo apt-get install build-essential```
 3.  Please update your kernel to lates one 
       ```sudo apt-get dist-upgrade```
Step 2: In terminal enter 
    git clone [https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new][2]

Step 3: Now enter “cd rtlwifi_new”.

Step 4: And now press “git checkout origin/extended -b extended”.

Step 5: sudo make install

Step 6: sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de

Step 7: sudo modprobe rtl8723de

if you got error like: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert ‘rtl8723de’: Required key not available
````

Above steps are included in that video
Or go to this [repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and follow the instructions